# Return the biggest but no more than a given float number using a given list of floats

Tags: python

This year, our school is holding a tug of war competition between classes, me and my classmates are eager to join, but we're not sure who to join the race, so I decided to code a program about it.
Here is my attempt with recursion, but it can only handle integer inputs, but the weight that my teacher gave us are float numbers. Is there any way to find the biggest weight combination but no more than the weight class (`target`)? Also, there is a participant limit, the number participants should be exactly the same as `participants_needed`.

```py
def allPossibleCombinations(target: int, using: dict[str: int], stack = None):
    # initialize
    if stack is None:
        stack = []
        using = dict(sorted(using.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])) # sort the dict using the values
    
    this_layer = []
    previous_layer = []
    
    if (using != {}) and (target - min(using.values()) >= 0):
        index = 0
        for name, number in using.items():
            if target - number == 0:
                this_layer.append(stack + [name])
            elif target - number < 0:
                break
            else:
                previous_layer.extend(allPossibleCombinations(target - number, dict(list(using.items())[index + 1:]), stack + [name]))
            index += 1
    return previous_layer + this_layer

def findCloset(target: int, participants_needed: int, participants: dict[str: int]): # if the target is impossible to form, try target - 1, target - 2 ...
    for i in range(target, min(participants.values()), -1):
        temp = allPossibleCombinations(i, participants)
        if temp != []:
            result = []
            for item in temp:
                if len(item) == participants_needed:
                    result.append(item)
            if result != []:
                print(f"{i}:", *result)
                break
    else:
        print("Impossible")
```

For example,  ("A", "B", "C"... are placeholder names)
`findCloset(460, 8, {"A": 53, "B": 71, "C": 42, "D": 58, "E": 49, "F": 75, "G": 56, "H": 46, "I": 49, "J": 51})` -> `459: ['H', 'E', 'J', 'A', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'F'], ['H', 'I', 'J', 'A', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'F']`

The thing that I want: (Handle floats)
`findCloset(460, 8, {"A": 53.4, "B": 71.0, "C": 42.3, "D": 57.6, "E": 48.9, "F": 75.1, "G": 56.2, "H": 46.1, "I": 48.7, "J": 51.3})` -> `???`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using `combinations` that works with `float` also:

```py
from itertools import combinations


def find_closest(target, participants_needed, participants):
    players = [x for x in participants.keys()]
    player_combinations = combinations(players, participants_needed)
    allowed_combinations = []
    for comb in player_combinations:
        total_weight = sum(participants[x] for x in comb)
        if total_weight <= target:
            allowed_combinations.append([total_weight, comb])
    return sorted(allowed_combinations, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

When:

```
result = find_closest(t, pn, p)
```

You can get, for example, top 3:

```
for i in result[:3]:
    print(f"Weight: {i[0]}; Players: {i[1]}")
```

Or just the highest:

```
print(f"Weight: {result[0][0]}; Players: {result[0][1]}")
```

Result for your example:

```
Weight: 459.6; Players: ('A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `range` function does not accept floats as arguments. You can cast the float value to the closest smaller/bigger integer using `math.floor()`/`math.ceil()` respectively. You have to import the math module using `import math` at the top of the file then change the first line in `findClosest` to:

```py
    for i in range(target, math.floor(min(participants.values())), -1):
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I need the values to be accurate......

Comment: The computation is still done on the floats, not on the casted integers. The change I made only affects the loop stop condition. Your code already handled floats properly, its just the line I modified that required a change.